# 'x' should probably not be assigned to 'y' warning in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm practicing Binary search trees. When I write this piece of code intellij throws warning: `'x' should probably not be assigned to 'y'`. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

I am assuming that assigning null to y first may have to do something with the warning though. But I'm not sure.

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root;

    public Node treeInsert(Node z) {
        Node x = root;
        Node y = null;
    
        while (x != null) {
            y = x;  // warning shows in this line
            if (z.key > x.key) x = x.right;
            else x = x.left;
        }
        z.parent = y;
        if (y != null) {
            if (z.key > y.key) y.right = z;
            else y.left = z;
        }
        return z;
    }
    
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private class Node {
        private int key;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;
        private Node parent;
    
        public Node(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the inspection description:

> Reports assignments and function calls in which the name of the target variable or the function parameter does not match the name of the value assigned to it.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> int x = 0;
> int y = x; // x is used as a y-coordinate
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> int x = 0, y = 0;
> // x is used as a y-coordinate and y as an x-coordinate
> Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(y, x, 20, 20);
> ```

It seems that this inspection mistakes your variables as `x` and `y` coordinates and warns you that you mistakenly assign an x coordinate value to an y coordinate.

To fix this you should give better names to your variables:

```
public Node treeInsert(Node z) {
    Node currentNode = root;
    Node parentNode = null;

    while (currentNode != null) {
        parentNode = currentNode;  // warning shows in this line
        if (z.key > currentNode.key) currentNode = currentNode.right;
        else currentNode = currentNode.left;
    }
    z.parent = parentNode;
    if (parentNode != null) {
        if (z.key > parentNode.key) parentNode.right = z;
        else parentNode.left = z;
    }
    return z;
}
```